# JQuery show and hide and class name wont display after first click

Tags: jquery, html

I'm new to Jquery and I have been trying to show and hide the list of Categories when I click on the element `<li class="show">Categories</li>` as well as change the class name from show to close. I can get the categories and class name to change on the first click but not on the second click or any other click after the first click.

HTML

```
<nav>
    <ul id="nav">
        <li class="show">Categories</li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<nav id="categories">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Category 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Category 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Category 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Category 4</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

JQuery

```
$('.show').click(function(){
    $('#categories').show();
    $(this).addClass('close').removeClass('show');
});  

$('.close').click(function(){
    $('#categories').hide();
    $(this).addClass('show').removeClass('close');
});
```

Comment: Of course it's not working. You're removing the `show` class when you click on it. So the event is no more attached to the element.

Answer (score 2):

Currently what you are using is called a "direct" binding which will only attach to element that exist on the page at the time your code makes the event binding call.

You need to use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) delegated-events approach, when generating elements dynamically or **manipulation selector (like removing and adding classes).**

i.e.

```
$(document).on('event','selector',callback_function)
```

*Example*

```
$(document).on('click', ".show", function(){
    //Your code
    $('#categories').show();
    $(this).addClass('close').removeClass('show');
});
$(document).on('click', ".close", function(){
    //Your code
    $('#categories').hide();
    $(this).addClass('show').removeClass('close');
});
```

---

However A better solution for your particular scenario is add another class and bind event using that

*Add a class*

```
<li class="categories show">Categories</li>
```

*Modify Script*

```
$('.categories').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('show close');
    $('#categories').toggle($(this).hasClass('show'));
});
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('.categories').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('show close');
    $('#categories').toggle($(this).hasClass('show'));
  }).click();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul id="nav">
    <li class="show categories">Categories</li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<nav id="categories">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Category 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Category 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Category 3</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Category 4</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Hello, this displayed my show css in place of my close css and vice versa crazy. Other then that it works fine,

Comment: This did not work I think the id and class selectors are in the wrong place in the jquery code.

Comment: I figured it out there is an extra .click()

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **[event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** on dynamically added/changed elements.

```
$(document).on('click', '.show', function(){
    $('#categories').show();
    $(this).toogleClass('close show');
});  

$(document).on('click', '.show', function(){
    $('#categories').hide();
    $(this).toogleClass('close show');
});
```